# How come the image.height is not the proper size?

Tags: html, css, image, image-size

When I have an image from 950x500 and output it like so:

```
<img src="http://full/url/to/image.png" />
```

There is a weird 3px in height space below the image. When asking javascript about it, it will indeed say the size is 950x503. While the image is really (check multiple times) 500 in size. It appears that the image tag does this how can this be fixed?

Note that the image must also remain to function dynamic. So if I were to set width of the image to 100% the height will resize accordingly.

Comment: How exactly do you "ask javascript" for height? The idea with `display:block` should work, though.

Comment: there is no need to use display:block, if you apply the height and width normally from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the answer is, set your image display on block like so:

```
img { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of putting `display :block;` beacuse this gonaa effect all the image tag though there is no harm, but the right way is this :

```
<img src="http://full/url/to/image.png" height="950" width="500"/>
```

Comment: My images are dynamic in width, the height will resize accordingly. But indeed you should not use this globally ;)

Comment: you should have mentioned that in your question because just with this "dynamic" word things become more complicated at times...